# how to specify a model with more than one nested random effect in `heavy` package in R

Tags: r, mixed-models

I am attempting to run a mixed model that, using `lme4` would be represented as `std_brain ~ type*taught*std_beh + (1|subject/cluster_name) + (1|subject:run)`.

However, I have a heavy-tailed distribution and I was hoping to be able to use the `heavy` package.  I can't figure out how to represent multiple nested random effects.  The package documentation gives the example:

```
 data(dental)
    fm0 <- heavyLme(distance ~ age * Sex, random = ~ age, groups = ~ Subject,
      data = dental, family = Student(df = 4))
    summary(fm0)
```

which includes one non-nested random effect.

I thought maybe `heavy` was an extension of `nmle` but reading the longer instructions for specifying random effects there

> `random` optionally, any of the following: (i) a one-sided formula of
> the form ~ x1 + ... + xn | g1/.../gm, with x1 + ... + xn specifying
> the model for the random effects and g1/.../gm the grouping structure
> (m may be equal to 1, in which case no / is required). The random
> effects formula will be repeated for all levels of grouping, in the
> case of multiple levels of grouping; (ii) a list of one-sided formulas
> of the form ~ x1 + ... + xn | g, with possibly different random
> effects models for each grouping level. The order of nesting will be
> assumed the same as the order of the elements in the list; (iii) a
> one-sided formula of the form ~ x1 + ... + xn, or a pdMat object with
> a formula (i.e. a non-NULL value for formula(object)), or a list of
> such formulas or pdMat objects. In this case, the grouping structure
> formula will be derived from the data used to fit the linear
> mixed-effects model, which should inherit from class "groupedData";
> (iv) a named list of formulas or pdMat objects as in (iii), with the
> grouping factors as names. The order of nesting will be assumed the
> same as the order of the order of the elements in the list; (v) an
> reStruct object. See the documentation on pdClasses for a description
> of the available pdMat classes. Defaults to a formula consisting of
> the right hand side of fixed.

isn't helping me specify a model that `heavy` accepts. I have tried a bunch of different ways; I don't know if it's helpful to list them all here. `'\' isn't relevant for factors` is a common error I'm getting.

How do I specify my model?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your experimental design: `cluster_name` and `subject` are crossed random effects within `subject`, i.e. observations from each `cluster_name` can be found in each `run` and *vice versa*? If not (e.g. if you can define a nesting order `subject/cluster_name/run` or `subject/run/cluster_name` that is a close enough approximation) then you should probably go with the best approximate nested specification.

If you really need crossed effects with `heavy` I'm afraid you might be out of luck.

The older `lme`-style random effects formulas (besides being specified as a separate `random =` argument) do not easily allow for non-nested random effects specifications. *If* `heavy` will accept the more general classes of random effects that `lme` uses (i.e. `pdBlocked`), you **may** be able hack crossed random effects - see [this example](https://gist.github.com/bbolker/83c1ff036d4850d7dc4ca832e354f6a8) and the third bullet point [here](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#nested-or-crossed).

However, especially as `heavy` is currently archived on CRAN (Sep 2022), I would suggest that you try out the `robustlmm` package or, if you can handle the Bayesian rabbit hole, the `brms` package, as suggested in the comments to [this CrossValidated question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/459404/r-package-for-implementing-linear-mixed-model-with-multivariate-t-distribution).

Comment: run and cluster_name are fully crossed and nested within subject. Observations from each run can be found for each cluster_name and vice versa.  But maybe the nested aproach you're suggesting is a close enough approximation. I have checked out robustlmm and brms and right now I'm actually just trying to understand/build some intuition for why I get such different results with different packages/methods.  So I was curious about heavy, to compare a frequentist heavy tailed approach to what I already tried in brms.

Comment: As a bit of a hack, you could try both nested approximations and see whether one seems better than the other (or, from your knowledge, which grouping variable is more/less likely to vary independently of the other?)

Comment: When I try either, I get this error: `some subjects with insuficient observations, unable to carry out the parameter estimation.` I'll work on understanding that.

Comment: If you're interested in some serious guinea-piggery, I just pushed a `glmmTMB` branch that allows a t-distributed response: `remotes::install_github("glmmTMB/glmmTMB/glmmTMB@t_family")` **might** work. (1) dispersion parameter is currently reported incorrectly (2) don't know how well estimating df will work; you may want to use `map = list(thetaf = factor(NA)), start = list(thetaf = log(df))` for a specified df parameter.

Comment: Thanks!  At the moment I have a long-running R process going but I'll check it out when it completes.